# "1-8-width" or "1-8-inch-width" in URL path?

Tags: url

For a product URL which is better form?

```
1-8-width-ao-sanding-belts
```

or

```
1-8-inch-width-ao-sanding-belts
```

Would this be served as 1/8" or 18 inch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spell it out unambigously:

```
/eighth-inch-width-ao-sanding-belts
```

Comment: Do I lose value they didn't do it that way in the first place?  301 Redirects?

Comment: Absolutely correct! It is best to make any URI readable and understandable by humans so that it is unambiguous - that way search engines can better understand. Short-cutting in these cases will confuse the semantic analysis and whatever search benefit you will receive. When in doubt - spell it out!

Comment: @MattMcLennan that would also be the case with your original question, would it not?